# Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

It seems as though my `PHP` is trying to log in to the `MySQL` database with a username I am not supplying.

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'radiocaf'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/radiocaf/public_html/layout.php on line 16
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/radiocaf/public_html/layout.php on line 16
```

I am definitely supplying a password, and am not using "radiocaf" as the username in my connect file, so after 3 hours of staring, I still can't work out where I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

**psl-config.php:**

```
define("HOST", "localhost");

define("USER", "carl");

define("PASSWORD", "xxxxxxxxx");

define("DATABASE", "wlist");
```

**db_connect.php**

```
include_once 'psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

**and then finally, the main page which is where I am receiving the error (I have cut out the HTML between the PHP:**

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Include Connection PHP and connect
include_once('includes/db_connect.php');

//Check Connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
};
if (!$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM users)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM members)
) results
ORDER BY Name DESC")){
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)){
printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

<HTML>

    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
        $x=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
        if ($x<10){
            echo "<tr><td width='400' height='30' background='../images/green1.jpg'>".$row["Name"]."</td></tr>";
        }

        $x++;

        if ($x == 10){
            echo "<tr><td width='400' height'30' background='../images/green1.jpg'>More...</td></tr>";
            break;
        }
        endwhile;
        echo "</table>";

<HTML>

$mysqli->close();
```

The surrounding `HTML` is just the layout of the page, essentially just a photoshop layout, sliced and exported to web.

I am fairly new to `PHP` and so I hope this question is as explained as possible.

---

### Edit:

Thanks so much guys, I apologise that this question seemed poor to some of you that you flagged it. Unfortunately I wouldn't have seen the "typos" as I really didn't know that I was attempting to use both `mysql` and `mysqli` and that they couldn't "communicate" with each other. Another issue I found was Dreamweaver uploaded the code from **layout.php** as **db_connect.php**. This doesn't explain (to me at least) how any connection was being made to bring up the access denied error for 'radiocaf'@'localhost' though.

Here's the old code lines I changed (in **layout.php**):

```
if (!$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
```

changed to:

```
if (!$query = "SELECT * FROM (

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
```

And that's all it took, but I am entirely grateful! Thanks again everyone!

Comment: If you're using mysqli, then use mysqli. You're interspersing mysql function calls, which is your problem. mysqli and mysql are two entirely different, unrelated APIs.

Comment: It says the error is in `layout.php`, have you checked that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are conflicting `MySQL` and `MySQLi`. MySQL and MySQLi are two  different methods

Warning is:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): .....
```

But you're connecting database with `mysqli`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);.
```

Warning in `php.net`:

> **MySQL** extension was **deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0**. Instead, the [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I can see why the question has been flagged as off-topic due to typographic errors, but I really am new to this and thought I was doing okay. I appreciate you pointing out that there is a difference, I have since sorted the code and it now works!

Comment: Yes! I have edited the original question to show the two lines of code that was changed to get the code to work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Include Connection PHP and connect
//include_once('includes/db_connect.php');
$con=mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

//Check Connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
};
if (!$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM users)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM members)
) results
ORDER BY Name DESC")){
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)){
printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
?>
<HTML>
<body>
  <?php
    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
        $x=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
        if ($x<10){
            echo "<tr><td width='400' height='30' background='../images/green1.jpg'>".$row["Name"]."</td></tr>";
        }

        $x++;

        if ($x == 10){
            echo "<tr><td width='400' height'30' background='../images/green1.jpg'>More...</td></tr>";
            break;
        }
        endwhile;
        echo "</table>";
        $mysqli->close();
?>
</body>
<HTML>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpfull if you described what changes you've made in your answer.

Comment: I have only used mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: if (!$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM (

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: You should add that explanation to your question :)

Comment: Thank you Abdulla/Mayuresh, I appreciate your help, I have since sorted the code, as I am new to MySQL through PHP I didn't realise there was two different extensions and that both mysql and mysqli could talk to each other. I now know that is not the case!